# Missing trailing slash after tld breaks ssl redirection from external link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have changed my website to ssl. It is working ok and all links internal to the website work but external links to ther http version are broken because the trailing slash at the end of the domain name is missing eg

`astarmathsandphysics dot com/a-level-physics-notes/thermal-physics-and-gases/a-level-physics-notes-prevosts-theory-of-heat-exchange.html`

is missing slash after .com on redirection

I need to force the trailing slash. In the apache2 config file I have redirected to ssl version with trailing slash and inserted this code in my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Also redirecting from non ssl www to ssl non www inserts an extra slash after .com

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do three things:

- Remove trailing slash if URL is not a directory
- Redirect www URLs to non-www
- Redirect http URLs to https

At least, that's what your .htaccess is telling me. Now for the issues.

---

For the first rule, the `(.*)` matches the entire request URI minus trailing slash, if it exists. Which means you only need `$1` on the second part, not `/$1` which would produce a double slash. This would be rewritten as:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Now for the second rule. You basically have the same double slash issue here, since `$1` captured the full request URI, including the beginning slash. Rewritten it would look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

And since that rule is just copying the entire request URI, the following rule would be equivalent:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%(REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The final rule is fine, with the exception that if you want this to be permanent you should use `R=301` instead of the implicit 302 redirect. Also, you shouldn't omit the `^` and `$` as a best practice. Rewritten as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Of further note, you only need `RewriteEngine on` once in the file.

---

So all together, the rules would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%(REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```